# Getting IndexError: list assignment index out of range in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, python-3.x

I am trying to delete last 5 elements i.e. '%20' from list arr:-

```
arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
length = 30
print(length)
print(len(arr))
print(arr)
for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    print(arr[x])
for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    del arr[x]
print(arr)
```

But I am getting following output. I am not getting why `print(arr[x])` works but `del arr[x]` doesn't:-

```
30
35
['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
%20
%20
%20
%20
%20
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
     del arr[x]
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index goes out of range because if you delete items from original array, the size of original array gets reduced.

Try `pop()` to delete items from last

```
arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
length = 30
print(length)
print(len(arr))
print(arr)
for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    print(arr[x])
for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    arr.pop()
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you delete each item the list gets shorter so your index runs off the end.
You can use slice notation `del arr[length:]` which will be much faster than pop.

Answer (score 0):

this is because u are iterating over a list that changes in each iteration.

```
>>> arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
>>> for x in range(length, y):
    del arr[30]


>>> arr
['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a']
```

pythonic way :

```
>>> arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']

>>> del arr[30: ]
>>> arr
['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `del arr[x:]` for solving this `error`.

```
arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']

length = 30
print(length)
print(len(arr))
print(arr)
for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    print(arr[x])

for x in range(length, len(arr)):
    del arr[x:]

print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers explain why you you got the error that you did.  This answer explains a *much* simpler way to do the same thing.

If you know you want to remove the last 5 elements, just make a slice that omits the last five elements.

```
arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
number_to_remove_from_end = 5
arr = arr[:-number_to_remove_from_end]
print(arr)
```

Output:

```
['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a']
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use the `del` keyword to ensure that the list ID remains the same then the following will work

```
arr = ['A', 't', 'u', 'l', '%20', 'K', 'r', 'i', 's', 'h', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'P', 'a', 't', 'n', 'a', '%20', 'B', 'i', 'h', 'a', 'r', '%20', 'I', 'n', 'd', 'i', 'a', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20', '%20']
number_to_remove_from_end = 5
del arr[-number_to_remove_from_end:]
print(arr)
```